# Jsonpath to grab parent field info with condition on child field

Tags: jsonpath, json-path-expression

We can use jsonpath to select values for given expressions, for the following example and question:

```
{
   "items": [
   {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "item1",
      "album": {
         "name": "Summer Trip",
         "meta": [
            {
             "name": "CreatedBy",
             "value": "Karen"
            },
            {
             "name": "Address",
             "value": "San Jose, CA"
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "item2",
      "album": {
         "name": "Winter Trip",
         "meta": [
            {
             "name": "CreatedBy",
             "value": "Lola"
            },
            {
             "name": "Address",
             "value": "Seattle, WA"
            }
         ]
      }
   }

   ] 
}
```

I would like to filter out items that its album's meta with condition as `name == "CreatedBy" and value == "Karen"`, and *return the item id and name*. For example:

```
{
   items: [
      {
         "id": 1,
         "name": "item1"
      }
   ]
}
```

By looking at how jsonpath works, **it seems once you go deeper into nested JSON nodes, it's not able to catch the parent node value**, for example, I can catch node values like

```
$..meta[?(@.name == 'CreatedBy' && @.value == "Karen")]
```

which returned me with the object inside **meta**, rather than its parent node **items**.

```
[
  {
     "name": "CreatedBy",
     "value": "Karen"
  }
]
```

Is it possible to use jsonpath to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: The closest query I got was `$.items[*][?(@.album.meta[0].name=="CreatedBy" && @.album.meta[0].value=="Karen")]['id','name']`. Works Only if the CreatedBy is at the same index position in every metadata. Tried with Jayway JsonPath Implementation. https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/. May not work with other implementations

Comment: That actually looks good, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [Jayway JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators) you can use filter operators.

**`contains` filter operator**

```
$.items[?(@.album.meta[?(@.name=='CreatedBy')].value contains 'Karen')]['id','name']
```

**`in` filter operator**

```
$.items[?('Karen' in @.album.meta[?(@.name=='CreatedBy')].value)]['id','name']
```

**Fixed index position**

```
$.items[*][?(@.album.meta[0].name=="CreatedBy" && @.album.meta[0].value=="Karen")]['id','name']
```

Online Test Tool : [Jayway JsonPath Evaluator](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/)